# testflight marketing url for stealth mode apps

Tags: ios, testflight, beta

So the Apple TestFlight for external testers is finally available. My app is in stealth mode. But I want to send it to a few people to beta test before I release. While going through the process for submitting my app for beta testing review, the submission process requires a `Marketing URL` which is supposed to be

> A URL with information about the app you are adding. This will be
>   visible to testers in the TestFlight app.

Given that my app is in stealth mode, I don't want to have a public url where I describe my app. So has someone already gone through this process and have some ideas how I might safely do this without divulging my app to the public? Thanks.

Comment: I'd say send an email to Apple asking about this.  Or just link to your company page maybe?

Comment: @borrrden that makes sense. I was hoping to expedite the process. That's why I ask here, in case someone else has already done so. But definitely, I will email Apple and wait for their answer. Thanks.

Comment: @KatedralPillon did you get any response ? i have the same problem. i dont even have a website for my project. how can i submit without marketing url?

Answer (score 0):

I created a document saying, "Information about this app has been shared privately with you." I put in a link to this document in TestFlight, and Apple accepted it.

Comment: where did you store the document? I'm having the same issue. I don't have a website.

Comment: Google Docs :) Create a public document.

Comment: It magically worked without a URL, but that solution is genius.